# Is it possible to use Oracle ManagedDataAccess in Xamarin Android?

Tags: oracle, xamarin

I have a Xamarin Android application targetting Android 8.1 (Oreo). I'm trying to connect to Oracle Database from Xamarin.

I added the following nugget packages : Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.core & System.Diagnstics.PerformanceCounter

[image]

When compiling my application, I have the following compilation error : **Can not resolve reference: `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`, referenced by `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter`, or remove the reference to `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`.    MyProjet.Android**

Is it possible to use ManagedDataAccess in Xamarin Android?

Comment: Because it was required by the compiler

Comment: For Oracle not to include a dependency to it in the Nuget packaging is not in good form, but that does mean it is not going to work on `Xamarin.Android`. Your best bet (and way better option in the long run) is to expose an authenticated REST api of the DB features you need and consume that on Xamarin.Forms|iOS|Android using HttpClient (possibly using something like RestSharp as a client wrapper)